# How to fix velocity ParseErrorException lexical error

Tags: velocity

Hi i am totally new to apache velocity and i am having *velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error* issue in my code, Can anybody help me in how to solve it?

Here is the code

```
#set ($file_name = ${ctx.FILE_NAME}.split('_REPORT'))
$file_name.get(0) - Some Text
```

And here is the error I am getting

```
Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error, Encountered: "s" (115), after : "." at *unset*[line 1, column 37]
at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.evaluate(RuntimeInstance.java:1301) ~[velocity-1.7.jar:1.7]
```

Can anybody help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#set ($file_name = ${ctx.FILE_NAME.split('_REPORT')})
$file_name.get(0) - Some Text
```

Or just:

```
#set ($file_name = $ctx.FILE_NAME.split('_REPORT'))
$file_name.get(0) - Some Text
```

Curly braces are only here to disambiguate a reference from surrounding text.